# Should I store uploaded filename in database?

Tags: database, file-upload, database-design, directory-structure, file-storage

I have a database table with an autoincrement ID as primary key.

For each record of this table, I can have up to 3 files, which can be publicly available so random filename generation is not mandatory, and these files are optional.

I think I have 2 possible solutions:

- Store a random generated filename in 3 nullable varchar column and store all the files in the same place:

  - columns: a | b | c
  - uploads/f6se54fse654.jpg
- Don't store the filenames, but place them in specific folders and name them the same than the primary key value:

  - uploads/a/1.jpg
  - uploads/b/1.jpg
  - uploads/c/1.jpg

With this last solution, I know that `uploads/a/1.jpg` belongs to record with `ID 1`, and is a file of type `a`. But I have to check if the file exists because the files are optional.

Do you think there is a good practice in all that? Or maybe there is a better approach?

Comment: Technically both will work.  I would however store the filename in the database. This way if you have to move files, restructure filesystems, ... you only have to write some SQL to make it match with your new file positions.

Comment: If the files get moved then the DB needs to be updated...

Comment: What would a motivation behind generating file names? You're asking an infrastructure design question without giving enough context.

Comment: I thought the context was clear, just imagine for example a user with a profile image, which is public, the user id is unique so I can use this id as a filename. What are the benefits of either store the file as `[ID].jpg` or store the name in this user database record ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the files you are talking about are intended to be displayed or downloaded by users (whether for visitors or for authenticated users, filtered by roles (ACL) or not), it is important to ensure (IMHO) that the user will not be able to guess other information other than the content of the concerned resource which has been sent to him. There is no perfect solution that can be applied to all cases without exception, so let's take an example to give you more explanations.

In order to enhance the security and total opacity of sensitive data, for example for the specific case of `uploads/users/7/invoices/3.pdf`, I think it would be wise to ensure that absolutely no one can guess the number of files that are potentially associated with the user or any other entity (because otherwise, in this example, we could imagine that there potentially are other accessible files - 1.pdf and 2.pdf). By design, we generally want to give access to files in a well defined and specific cases and context. However, this may not be the case for an image file which is intended to be seen by everyone (a profile photo, for example). That's why the context matters in some way.

If you choose to keep the auto-incremented identifiers as names to refer to your files, this can also give information about the size of the data stored in your database (`/uploads/invoices/128.pdf` informs that you may already have 127 invoices on your server) and potentially motivate unscrupulous people to try to reach resources that should never be fetched out of the defined context. This case may be less obvious if you choose to use some kind of unique generated identifiers (GUID).

I recommend that you read [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/) concerning the generation of (G)/(U)UIDs (a 128-bit hexadecimal numbers) to be stored in your database for each uploaded or created file. If you use MySQL in its latest version it is even possible to host this identifier in a `binary (16)` type which offers an automatic conversion to UUID, I let you read [this interesting topic](https://stackoverflow.com/%20questions%20/%2043056220%20/%20store-uuid-v4-in-mysql) associated with what I refer about. It will probably output this as `/uploads/invoices/b0016303-8e4f-487a-8c30-5dddf1ebf7e9.pdf` which is a lot better as long as you ensure that the generated identifier is unique hash.

It does not seem useful to me here to talk about performance issues because today there are many methods for caching files or path and urls, which avoid having to make requests each time in a lot of cases where a resource is called (often ordered by their popularity rank in bigdata cases).

Last, but not least, many web and mobile platform applications (I think of Slack, Discord, Facebook, Twitter...) which store a lot of media files every day which are often associated with accounts users, both public and confidential files and information, generate a unique hash for each of them.

Twitter is using its own unique identifier string (64-bits `BIGINT`) generator called [Twitter Snowflake](https://www.callicoder.com/distributed-unique-id-sequence-number-generator/) which you might be interesting to read too. It is based on the UNIX epoch value which is, by definition, unique at each millisecond tick.

There isn't a global and perfect solution which can be applied for everything but I hope that this will help you as you may want to take a deeper look in this and find the "best solution" for each context and entity you'll store and link files.